# Get warning messages through psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to call a plpgsql function through psycopg2 and see the warning messages.
I.e, I have this function:

```
create or replace function test_warning() returns void as $$
begin
raise warning 'this is only a test';
end; 
$$
language plpgsql;
```

and call it so in python:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.callproc("test_warning")
# or so:
cursor.execute('SELECT test_warning()')
```

Unfortunately the warning message as defined in plpgsql does not appear anywhere in the python output. 
Is there a way to get the warning message printed in the python output?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `notices` member of the `connection` is a list of the session's messages sent to the client up to that point:

```
for notice in conn.notices:
    print notice
```

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.notices

To get the last notice:

```
print conn.notices[-1]
```

If an exception is raised inside a function, and not caught, no warning will be received. That is because a function wraps an implicit transaction and everything inside that transaction is rolled back including warnings.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. But what if I use the same connection for many cursors? I tried resetting notices so: `conn.notices={}` but I got the exception TypeError: readonly attribute.  
And can I get the warning while the function is executed? Say, the function raises a warning and then a exception: I would like to see the warning before the exception is raised.

Comment: @Tomm you can clear the notices with `del conn.notices[:]`. You cannot have the notices while executing in sync mode. Maybe in async mode yes but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the reputation to comment on Clodoaldo's answer, but my solution for getting the latest notices (note that a query can generate several notices) is pretty straightforward:

```
def execute_query(query, conn):
    logger = logging.getLogger('test')
    nr_notices = len(conn.notices)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    for notice in conn.notices[nr_notices:]:
        logger.info(f'NOTICE: {notice}.')
```