# Get postgres messages through npgsql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, pgadmin

I am having an issue with my application, one of my requirements is to capture the messages that is output in postgres when I make a call to a PLPGSQL function, similarly to what is happening here:

[Get warning messages through psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236749/get-warning-messages-through-psycopg2)

Except my issues are in npgsql. I have my log manager set up:

```
NpgsqlLogManager.Provider = new ConsoleLoggingProvider(NpgsqlLogLevel.Trace, true, true);
```

And I make this call:

```
_db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT test_warning();");
```

test_warning is a custom sql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_warning()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
begin
raise info 'this is only a test';
end; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

and `_db` is the `IDbConnection`, and the query is made using Dapper. In my log messages, I am only getting the call to the function, as well as some other connection information:

```
DEBUG [40560] Opened connection to (Database Server)
TRACE [40560] Start user action
TRACE [40560] ExecuteNonScalar
DEBUG [40560] Executing statement(s):

                      SELECT test_warning()
TRACE [40560] End user action
TRACE [40560] Closing connection
TRACE [40560] Really closing connection
DEBUG [40560] Connection closed
```

No mention of the warning/info message.

Comment: [Notice Processing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-notice-processing.html) If you have the access to the connection handler then it is simple.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd ensure that function exists... I fired up postgres and could not run that query, so it's not an out of the box function.

Next, I'd try adjusting how I was making the call...

```
_db.CommandText = "SELECT test_warning()";
_db.ExecuteScalar();
```

Here's the docs: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html